# Можно ли убрать кнопку с панели ckeditor для мобильного устройства?

Tags: ckeditor

обнаружил что на мобильном устройстве, мой плагин emoji плохо работает, окно то всплывает то исчезает и с клавиатурой так же и это все циклически не переставая. Пока не знаю как это решить, но вопрос в следующем, можно ли убрать кнопку emoji именно на мобильной версии сайта?